# Issue on Using jQuery each() to Load Elements of Array in DOM Elements

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know how I can use the `.each()` to load each elements of array to the `button`s?

```js
var arr=["Left","Middle", "Right" ];
 $("button").each(function(){
        $(this).html(arr);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">x</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">x</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can. You use the `index` of each button in the DOM and use it to iterate through the array

```
var arr=["Left","Middle", "Right" ];
 $("button").each(function(i){
        $(this).html(arr[i]);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d14z32fq/

Answer (score 1):

**If** the array order is the desired, use the `index` parameter provided by the `.each()` method:

```
var arr = ["Left","Middle", "Right"];
$("button").each(function(i){
    $(this).html(arr[i]);
});
```